# how can i add one common loader or progress bar to entire project

Tags: angularjs, http, interceptor

I'm doing my project in angularjs ***how can i add one common loader or progress bar to entire project*** with css rather than calling show/hide block functions for every controller's div class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write an interceptor to do that. To learn about interceptor refer: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

But someone has already done all the works, so why re-invent the wheel! 
http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/

Comment: Failed to instantiate module inspinia due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=o...)
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:5000/js/plugins/common/angular.min.js:6:416
    at http://localhost:5000/js/plugins/common/angular.min.js:38:184
    at m (http://localhost:5000/js/plugins/common/angular.min.js:7:322)
    at h (http://localhost:5000/js/plugins/common/angular.min.js:37:275)

Comment: Thanks praveen i'm getting this error after following the instructions at link http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/

Answer (score 0):

Until you get the response you can put a waiting dialog..
after getting the response you can hide the dialog..
Here is a link of simple dialog using jquery [waitingDialog](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/Oe5XM)

And this dialog can be best used with angular and you can alter it according to your requirement so good luck..

Do it something like this

```
angular.module('app').factory('httpInterceptor', ['$q', '$rootScope',
    function ($q, $rootScope) {
        var loadingCount = 0;

        return {
            request: function (config) {
                if(++loadingCount === 1) $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:progress');
                return config || $q.when(config);
            },

            response: function (response) {
                if(--loadingCount === 0) $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:finish');
                return response || $q.when(response);
            },

            responseError: function (response) {
                if(--loadingCount === 0) $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:finish');
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        };
    }
]).config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
}]);
```

Then use event bound to `$rootScope` anywhere (preferable to use in directive or run block of app.js):

```
$rootScope.$on('loading:progress', function (){
    // show loading gif
});

$rootScope.$on('loading:finish', function (){
    // hide loading gif
});
```

You can read more about it here [codingsmackdown](http://codingsmackdown.tv/blog/2013/04/20/using-response-interceptors-to-show-and-hide-a-loading-widget-redux/)

Comment: It won't work for bunch of controllers. i need a loader which need to be automatically call when http requests are raised because i dont want to write waitingDialog for every controller separately.

Comment: you can call this when you call your service and on response you can hide it. It works for me. Can you tell me where exactly it is not working for you?

Comment: In our project i have nearly 50 controllers and every controller has 10 service calls if i do like as u suggested i need to hide/view windowDialog for every service call so that's not a good approach . i need a solution like when an http request has raised windowDialog should be visible and after getting the response it should be hide for all the controllers

Comment: oh okay then you got to use httpInterceptor, let me edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
angular-loading-bar 
http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/#

This is the best progress bar working in background.

Here is the documentation http://angular-js.in/loading-bar/

Also the demo is available there.

To change color of loading bar use css

```
#loading-bar .bar {
    background-color: #2CA01C;
}
```

Comment: its working! but can you tell me how to add my own color for default loading bar?

Comment: You need to add css on
#loading-bar .bar {
    background-color: #2CA01C;
}