# How to add progress bar on AngularJS download?

Tags: angularjs, progress-bar

HTML code:

```
<form id="pdfForm" class="display-inline" method="POST" action="{{document.PdfActionUrl}}">
    <button uib-tooltip="Download PDF" type="submit" ng-disabled="document.CaseStudies.length == 0" class="uui-button button-action"><span class="icons-action icon-action-load"></span></button>
</form>
```

AngularJS code:

```
$scope.jsonToDoc = function (doc) {
    document.PdfActionUrl = '/odata/DocumentsApi(' + document.Id + ')/API.DownloadPdf';
```

The server side code:

```
public HttpResponseMessage DownloadPdf([FromODataUri] Guid key)
{
    var document = _documentService.GetPdfDocument(key, Request.RequestUri.BaseUri(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["setting"]));

    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    response.Content = new StreamContent(document.Content);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = document.Name
    };

    return response;
}
```

I'm not sure what approach best fits to this case and how to calculate downloading real time.

Comment: I don't know about progress bar but you can add loading gif or loading template until fully download.

Comment: Ok. Is there any code sample?

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38177329/how-can-i-add-one-common-loader-or-progress-bar-to-entire-project/38177453#38177453